# Rotate element without return to original state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rotation

I want to do rotaion on my div with image on hover. But after I want set rotation to default without rotate div back. I try two ways. 
Css:

```
.rotate{
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;

    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
    transition-property: transform;

    overflow:hidden;

}

.rotate:hover
{
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

And jQuery:

```
var rotated_elems = [".small-blue-1", ".small-blue-2", ".small-blue-3", ".small-blue-4",
    ".small-blue-5", ".big-blue-6", ".animated_blue_1", ".animated_blue_2", ".animated_blue_3"];
$.each(rotated_elems, function (key, element) {
    $(element).hover(function () {
        $(this).animate(
            {rotation: 360},
            { duration: 500,
                step: function (now, fx) {
                    $(this).css({"transform": "rotate(" + now + "deg)"});
                }
            });
    });
});
```

In first (css) case elemes rotate back, in sexond (js) element rotate to 360. And on second hover nothing happens. But I want to rotate on the second hower, without back rotation. Can somebody help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style>
.rotate{
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
}
</style>
<script>
  element.addEventListener("mouseover", rotate, false);

  function rotate(){
    this.classList.add('rotate');
  }
</script>
```

loop through all the classes you need, but basic point is use mouseover instead of hover.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `mouseover` instead of `hover`.
I don't think that it is possible in CSS.